# SSIS SFTP : How to resolve "Unable to Upload: Socket read operation has timed out"?

Tags: ssl, ssis, ftp, sftp, ssis-2012

Using [the SSIS SFTP Extension](http://ssisextensions.codeplex.com/) and configured everything correctly.

However, I'm getting the following error any time I execute the SFTP task:

> Error: Error: Unable to Upload: Socket read operation has timed out
>
> at SSIS.Extensions.SFTP.SFTPConnection.ThrowException(String Message, Exception ex)
>   at SSIS.Extensions.SFTP.SFTPConnection.UploadFiles(List`1 fileList)
>   at SSIS.Extensions.SFTPTask.SFTPTask.Execute(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents, IDTSLogging log, Object transaction)

I have to being able to connect via **Implicit SSL**.

There are a couple of paid SSIS components that will do the trick, but I'm not willing to pay for them as they're expensive given they package a slew of other components I don't need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFTP does not use TLS/SSL (neither implicit nor explicit). Explicit/Implict TLS/SSL is used with FTP.

In other words SFTP is *not* FTP over TLS/SSL. It's a completely different and incompatible protocol.

So you are possibly trying to use SFTP component to connect to an implicit TLS/SSL FTP port (990). That cannot work.

- Make sure you know what protocol you need to use
- Use FTP task capable of TLS/SSL encryption, if it turns out that you need to use FTP.