# connecting to a FTP server that has a certificate using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ftp

I am trying to download files from a FTP site inside my production environment. The FTP site has been assigned with a certificate (pfx). The FTP port is 21.

Due to this certificate I am unable to download the content using FTP task in SSIS.

I tried using script task however I got the same error that ftp cannot accomplish the connection due to certificate.

I also tried with SFTP component but that gave me a error shown below

> [Execute: ] Error: Error: Unable to List: Socket read operation has
>   timed out
>
> at SSIS.Extensions.SFTP.SFTPConnection.ThrowException(String
>   Message, Exception ex)    at
>   SSIS.Extensions.SFTP.SFTPConnection.ListFiles(String remotePath)    at
>   SSIS.Extensions.SFTPTask.SFTPTask.Execute(Connections connections,
>   VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents
>   componentEvents, IDTSLogging log, Object transaction)

I googled the error and found out that SFTP does not use TLS/SSL (neither implicit nor explicit). Explicit/Implict TLS/SSL is used with FTP from the post

[SSIS SFTP : How to resolve "Unable to Upload: Socket read operation has timed out"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755916/ssis-sftp-how-to-resolve-unable-to-upload-socket-read-operation-has-timed-ou)

Is there a way to connect to FTP that has a certificate associated with it using SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.... We can use the FTP task itself to connect with a FTP that has a certificate associated with it.

Below are the workaround for this...

There are three SSL options when we create a FTP site in IIS.

1. Allow SSL
2. Require SSL
3. No SSL

NO SSL option will not allow SSL certificates to be used for the FTP
Allow and Require SSL provides the SSL feature for the FTP.

> In the FTP site that I had has the Require SSL option selected. I
>   changed that option to Allow SSL which still enables the SSL feature
>   for the FTP but allows the FTP task